# Direct2D Effects

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct2d

I am trying to follow instructions on creating *Custom Direct2D Effects*, as described in [Custom Effects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj710194(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Effect Shader Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn879810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I am getting into number of problems:

1. The "d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli" file in not found in my Windows SDK. I could only find it [here](https://github.com/gongminmin/UniversalDXSDK/blob/master/Include/d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli).
2. When trying to run `fxc` compiler with model set to `lib_4_0_level_9_1_ps_only` I get an error that this model is not supported.
3. When using `lib_4_0_level_9_1` instead, I get another compilation error, saying that static variables are not supported for libraries (and this static definition comes from the above HLSLI file, not from my code).

After all my goal is to create a pixel shader for Direct2D, which will be receiving number of textures as input. Maybe something in my environment is missing and I can't follow the examples (I'm using Windows 8.1). Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason you're compiling your shaders with the `lib` profile?  Custom D2D effects are usually pixel shaders (`ps` profile).

Comment: I just tried to follow the instructions in the above guide: [Effect Shader Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn879810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), where it said to use `of the profiles listed under “HLSL shader linking”` from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509709(v=vs.85).aspx#Profiles) list. I'm starting to think it only works with Windows 10 SDK.